# Samba service auto start at boot on modern Debian/Kali/

Tags: linux, samba, services, autostart

How can I set the **Samba** server to ***autostart*** at boot...
( like the old systemd -> systemctl enable  )

```
update-rc.d smbd enable
```

does not work also... after reboot the

```
service --status-all
```

says that smbd service is stopped...
couriously the co-service **nmbd** starts ok!

---

?should I put the

```
service samba start
```

in the ***/etc/bashrc***
or in  ***/etc/profile***

? ¨\o/¨ ??

Comment: Did you install a recent version of Kali/Debian? Because as far as I know they should have systemd, But maybe you installed the `init` deamon? Or are you running Kali/Debian inside a container (docker,podman)?

Comment: Try also: `update-rc.d smbd defaults`

Answer (score 2):

Usually the samba is set to be started automatically after boot while installing the samba package. You described the elder script way which is used with systems using `init`. Debian started using `systemd` a few versions back. The command is:

```
# systemctl [start|stop|restart|reload|enable|disable|status] smbd.service
```

`reload` reread the config

`enable` set service to be started after boot

`disable` remove service from the autostart

There are more daemons/services included in the samba package such as smbd, nmbd, and daemon for active directory.

Answer (score -1):

*** SOLVED ***

the problem was in the ***symbolic links*** at **Runlevel** folders
( /etc/rc0.d to /etc/rc6.d )

to resolve force the *symlinks* removal...
and then force the *symlinks* re-install...

```
update-rc.d -f smbd remove
update-rc.d -f smbd defaults
update-rc.d enable
```

then reboot and issue a

```
service --status-all
```

and you should see the service enabled and running...

Comment: Pretty certain that you'll make your system hard to maintain if you introduce rc.d scripts instead of using the standard systemd way of managing services